# Uniqueness of non-autonomous ODE

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

From Picard-Lindelöf Theorem it is well known that, roughly speaking, an ODE $\dot x= f(x)$, with continously differentiable or Lipschitz continous right-hand side (RHS) has a unique solution (in some interval).

What I struggle with is the following: For a given non-autonomous RHS $f(x,d)$, e.g. $f=d(t)x^2+1$ with continous function $d(\cdot)$, I can locally obtain the following: $|f(x,d)-f(y,d)|\leq L |d(t)||x-y|$.Is the assertion about uniqueness of the solution still valid for a non-uniform Lipschitz constant $L d$?

Comment: Please check more sources about Picard-Lindelöf. It is usually formulated for the non-autonomous case. // Note that a continuous $d$ is locally bounded.

Comment: @LutzLehmann With locally bounded, do you mean that I could write the Lipschitz constant directly as $K=L•max(d)$?

Comment: Yes, for any bounded set inside the domain.